# Understanding a spectral theorem's proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I want to understand the proof of the following theorem: "If $f$ is a self-adjoint operator of a euclidean space, then $f$ is diagonalisable"

**It goes like this :**

There are 2 steps that derive directly from a theorem that says that f is diagonalisable iff:

(a) its characteristic polynomial can be written in a polynomial-split, i.e, $P_f(X) = (-1)^n(X-\lambda_1)^{\alpha_1}...(X-\lambda_p)^{\alpha_p}$ with $\lambda_1...\lambda_p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha_1+...+\alpha_p=n (\lambda_i$ being the eigenvalues of $f $ and $\alpha_i$ being the multiplicity of the eigenvalues.

(b) $dim E_{\lambda_i} = \alpha_i$

The first part of the proof prove $(a)$ and the second part proves $(b)$:

- Let us show that the characteristic polynomial of f can be written in a polynomial split, which means that all the eigenvalues of $f$ are real.

*In order to prove $(a)$, all they do is show that all eigenvalues are real, but they don't show the other requirements (that $P_f(X) = (-1)^n(X-\lambda_1)^{\alpha_1}...(X-\lambda_p)^{\alpha_p}$ and that $\alpha_1+...+\alpha_p = n$) Does the fact that $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$ imply the other requirements?*

Comment: You can always factorize the characteristic polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ in that way, if you show that all eigenvalues are real, then you can write the characteristic polynomial in that way. The fact that $\sum_{i}\alpha_i=n$ only says that the polynomial has as many roots as its degree.

Comment: The more difficult part of the proof is to show $(b)$.

Comment: Thank you, how do we know that $P_f(X)$ has as many roots as its degree though?

Comment: There is a fundamental theorem that says that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $p(\lambda)=0$, then $(x-\lambda)\mid p(x)$, that is, $(x-\lambda)$ is a factor of $p(x)$. (This follows from the long division algorithm of polynomials). If $p(x)$ has more roots then its degree, then the product of all these factors has a higher degree than $p(x)$ and divides $p(x)$, but that's impossible.

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that any non-zero polynomial $p(x)$ has a root $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Hence such a factorization exists.

Comment: Could you give me the name of the theorem (if a name is attributed to it of course)?

Comment: I stated two theorems, the first can be found here http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac02/fac02.html. It is the statement before the exercises (and is very easy and elementary to show). The second theorem is called the fundamental theorem of algebra and states that any polynomial can be factorized over $\mathbb{C}$. (That one is not so easy to show and always requires some theory to tackle it).